# jQuery Limit the amount of characters i'm loading/appending?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm loading this content but;

-how can i limit the amount of characters that I am loading? *( so it only grabs the first 100 characters)*

-is this a good way of appending or loading html from another page on my site?

I also want to keep my script short and minimal

`if($('#description').length){$("#brief").load("/profile/contact/ #content p");}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to produce a back-end page that only outputs the content you need, not all the extra stuff. In short, you are using `load()` wrong. well... you are using it "correctly", but in a very inefficient way.

Comment: @SirB You already know the answer to that question; it's loading an entire document just to display a small part of it.